# Should you return javascript (.js.erb) from the Rails server OR use the native JS callback mechanism when updating the page after a Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am doing an ajax call (using JQuery) and the Rails controller needs to return a partial so I can update the page after the ajax call.  It seems to me there are 2 ways of doing this.  In the controller, you filter for ajax calls (request.xhr?) and return:

1. a .js.erb which gets executed on the client side as part of the Ajax call itself (dataType : script).  This .js.erb file manipulates the DOM and injects the partials' html, something like this:

   $('#content').html("<%= escape_JavaScript(render :partial => 'success') %>");
2. a partial ((dataType : html).  You have a success callback method on the ajax call that then performs the inject, something like this:

   $.post( url, send_data,
     function( data ) {
         $( "#result" ).empty().append( data );
     }

These 2 solutions both work perfectly, I just don't know which one is considered better coding practice and easier to maintain down the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second option is ideal. The Server should never be concerned with the Client.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the second option too, because it makes sense when talking from a RESTful perspective.

I talk about this in a blog entry ["Rails, REST and JS - We're doing it wrong"](http://blog.wilcoxd.com/blog/2011/05/22/rails-rest-and-js-tldr-were-doing-it-wrong/)